# Private video and other content for newsletter subscribers only

Tags: security, video, private, newsletter

I'm after some advice or guidance on newsletters please. Hopefully that's not breaking the rules of stackoverflow. I've spent an hour Googling and can't really find what I'm looking for.

I'm in the process of designing a website for a client who wants to offer content such as videos to subscribers. Originally we were going to do this on a secured Wordpress install with logins. However we've since discussed perhaps doing this through a newsletter.

Is there anyway we can secure content such as links to specific web pages, videos or other content, within a newsletter, only for viewing by those who are subscribed to the newsletter? So it may be a link to the private content, from within that week's newsletter.

I was thinking down the line of unique URLs, similar to those used for resetting passwords.

The idea is to offer that content only to those who have clicked the link within the newsletter and hide it from others.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Everyone that knows the link can watch the video – so any user that receives your newsletter can post it f.e. onto a social networking site, and everyone following the link from there will be able to watch it as well. If you don’t want that, then you will have to use login protection instead. If you’re fine with that, then whether or not you should use “unique URLs” depends on if you need additional features such as tracking which recipient followed the link. If not, then the URL doesn’t need to be “unique”, but only ”secret”, meaning published via the newsletter only and nowhere else.

Comment: Hi Cbroe, thanks for your reply. I think we may have to go down the road of logins then.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much protection you want you could use URL tokenisation which essentially adds a 'token' to the URL and the server can then only provide the content when the token is validated. The validation could be based on some login cookie like approach or on geographic region, network etc.

If you actually want to protect the content from being copied and distributed then you need to use some form of encryption and some system to supply the encryption key to the end user (this is usually referred to as Digital Rights Management - DRM).

Several of the big video hosting providers (e.g. Ooyla, Brightcove etc) provide a service that does this and will allow you include a access restricted and/or encrypted video in your site. Bright cove, as an example, have a summary of their approach here:

- https://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/content-protection-drm

Comment: Thanks Mick. I may have to rethink this. I think DRM may be a bit overboard for what we're after.